# Missing records in SQL server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I have a database in place with a client that seems to lose data overnight. They enter records and exit the system, and then claim to not be able to find them again the next day.

The ID numbers in the Primary Key Index of the affected tables do seem to have gaps in, when they should be auto-incremented and continuous. The client does not have the facility to delete records, so there seems to be an issue.

I have tried using `DBCC CHECKDB` and `DBCC REINDEX` but the records do not re-appear and the issue continues.

On exit from the VB.NET 2010 app, I use the following to write the record for each table:

```
Me.binds_Tablename1.EndEdit()
Me.binds_Tablename2.EndEdit()
TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Dataset_1)
```

This system has worked fine for 2 years, but is now playing up. Could database corruption be the issue?

Comment: Hard to tell whats going on! Have you used a sql server audit and a database audit specification to find out who/which process has accessed the tables using delete statements?

Comment: Unlikely to be the database. Occam's Razor would indicate that if neither the database nor the code have changed recently then you need to look at the data/users/phases of the moon etc as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now appears to be sorted - the client was running a mirrored hard disk, one of which was starting to fall over with SMART error reports. Since this was replaced, the problem has not re-occurred.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

since this just started, is it possible that they are entering 2012 somewhere or it is related to the year 2012, maybe this value does not exist in a lookup table, the transaction gets rolled back

When a transaction rolls back the identity value is NOT reused, this is why you see gaps, you need to find out why you have rollbacks

Comment: Thanks - the issue actually started late last year. I will check out the rollbacks though.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, the `TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll()` method wraps the updates in a transaction.  Auto-increment fields increment outside of transactions, so I would guess that some of your transactions may be rolling back.